# How to filtering in Django use specific user

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I try to filtering django some specific user. I try with list but it not working. Do you have any solution.

```
list = ['bill gates','elon musk','aamir khan','larry page']
allPosts = Post.objects.filter(author=list)
```

**When I change list filter can work dynamically**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `__in`:

```
my_list = ['bill gates','elon musk','aamir khan','larry page']
allPosts = Post.objects.filter(author__in=my_list)
```

Note: Never use python built in functions (Ex: `list`) as variable names. It would be better to avoid the need for this by choosing a different variable name.